# Dynamic attribute list rabl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rabl

I'm trying to get a json view that uses rabl to have custom attributes sent by the request, so for example if a model has

```
:id, :first_name, :last_name
```

I wanna be able to just call the values I want like say id and first_name only, so what I dont know is how to convert something like a string to the attributes that rabble has to return.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all create variable in controller set by request. 
For example

```
@attributes_choose_by_user = params[:attrs]
```

them just pass that variable as parameter to attributes in an viewer

```
# app/views/posts/index.rabl
collection @posts
attributes @attributes_choose_by_user
```

request should look like this

```
GET /posts?attrs[]=id&attrs[]=first_name&attrs[]=last_name
```